# Numpy.argsort - can't see what's wrong

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am trying to sort a numpy array using the argsort function.

Unfortunately this is not working and I can't see why :(

The code is:

```
import numpy as np

distance = np.array([38.26,  33.01,  32.33,  30.77,  37.96,  44.37,  32.72,  36.56,
        27.77,  33.62,  42.85,  34.6 ,  32.04,  27.49,  49.64,  51.85,
        44.37,  38.26,  46.93,  40.45,  40.72,  39.7 ,  34.12,  36.9 ,
        34.6 ,  34.  ,  36.56,  39.29,  38.6 ,  32.33,  32.65,  40.72,
        43.85,  47.89,  33.62,  35.24,  42.5 ,  36.97,  28.36,  37.57,
        37.25,  25.54,  29.6 ,  37.25,  40.45,  32.04,  40.45,  31.4 ,
        41.78,  35.89,  59.24,  51.2 ,  57.22,  35.54,  50.09,  40.33,
        50.58,  29.77,  51.97,  34.33,  29.  ,  43.81,  40.84,  45.62,
        39.77,  54.5 ,  40.36,  40.93,  43.28,  37.61,  45.05,  45.05,
        45.94,  45.05,  49.37,  52.56,  54.08,  53.89,  44.41,  39.25,
        36.01,  36.01,  40.93,  43.29,  38.16,  47.56,  54.5 ,  44.98,
        40.36,  36.5 ,  37.01,  46.21,  40.4 ,  30.29,  38.65,  41.49,
        40.9 ,  46.85,  32.26,  40.33,  50.58,  40.93,  59.41,  48.1 ,
        51.25,  66.76,  30.26,  61.7 ,  51.14,  64.8 ,  52.49,  48.25,
        55.24,  38.74,  41.48,  51.2 ,  51.25,  73.73,  66.05,  40.84,
        57.85,  39.2 ,  67.13,  46.98,  55.78,  62.08,  46.28,  46.21,
        48.8 ,  60.84,  62.6 ,  76.85,  48.8 ,  47.53,  43.97,  68.29,
        51.25,  50.57,  45.  ,  57.22,  54.5 ,  57.22,  40.93,  56.48,
        55.78,  53.89,  45.94,  51.25,  50.  ,  43.81])
```

To debug it, I am printing the distance array together with the argsort:

```
print np.array(zip(distance, distance.argsort()))
```

What I get is this. It looks wrong, because for example 30.77 is smaller than 32.33, but 32.33 is marked as 8 and 30.77 as 38. What am I doing wrong?

```
[[  38.26   41.  ]
 [  33.01   13.  ]
 [  32.33    8.  ]
 [  30.77   38.  ]
 [  37.96   60.  ]
 [  44.37   42.  ]
 [  32.72   57.  ]
 [  36.56  106.  ]
 [  27.77   93.  ]
 [  33.62    3.  ]
 [  42.85   47.  ]
 [  34.6    45.  ]
 [  32.04   12.  ]
 [  27.49   98.  ]
 [  49.64    2.  ]
 [  51.85   29.  ]
 [  44.37   30.  ]
 [  38.26    6.  ]
 [  46.93    1.  ]
 [  40.45    9.  ]
 [  40.72   34.  ]
 [  39.7    25.  ]
 [  34.12   22.  ]
 [  36.9    59.  ]
 [  34.6    24.  ]
 [  34.     11.  ]
 [  36.56   35.  ]
 [  39.29   53.  ]
 [  38.6    49.  ]
 [  32.33   80.  ]
 [  32.65   81.  ]
 [  40.72   89.  ]
 [  43.85   26.  ]
 [  47.89    7.  ]
 [  33.62   23.  ]
 [  35.24   37.  ]
 [  42.5    90.  ]
 [  36.97   43.  ]
 [  28.36   40.  ]
 [  37.57   39.  ]
 [  37.25   69.  ]
 [  25.54    4.  ]
 [  29.6    84.  ]
 [  37.25    0.  ]
 [  40.45   17.  ]
 [  32.04   28.  ]
 [  40.45   94.  ]
 [  31.4   113.  ]
 [  41.78  121.  ]
 [  35.89   79.  ]
 [  59.24   27.  ]
 [  51.2    21.  ]
 [  57.22   64.  ]
 [  35.54   99.  ]
 [  50.09   55.  ]
 [  40.33   88.  ]
 [  50.58   66.  ]
 [  29.77   92.  ]
 [  51.97   46.  ]
 [  34.33   44.  ]
 [  29.     19.  ]
 [  43.81   20.  ]
 [  40.84   31.  ]
 [  45.62   62.  ]
 [  39.77  119.  ]
 [  54.5    96.  ]
 [  40.36   67.  ]
 [  40.93  101.  ]
 [  43.28  142.  ]
 [  37.61   82.  ]
 [  45.05  114.  ]
 [  45.05   95.  ]
 [  45.94   48.  ]
 [  45.05   36.  ]
 [  49.37   10.  ]
 [  52.56   68.  ]
 [  54.08   83.  ]
 [  53.89  149.  ]
 [  44.41   61.  ]
 [  39.25   32.  ]
 [  36.01  134.  ]
 [  36.01    5.  ]
 [  40.93   16.  ]
 [  43.29   78.  ]
 [  38.16   87.  ]
 [  47.56  138.  ]
 [  54.5    73.  ]
 [  44.98   71.  ]
 [  40.36   70.  ]
 [  36.5    63.  ]
 [  37.01  146.  ]
 [  46.21   72.  ]
 [  40.4   127.  ]
 [  30.29   91.  ]
 [  38.65  126.  ]
 [  41.49   97.  ]
 [  40.9    18.  ]
 [  46.85  123.  ]
 [  32.26  133.  ]
 [  40.33   85.  ]
 [  50.58   33.  ]
 [  40.93  103.  ]
 [  59.41  111.  ]
 [  48.1   132.  ]
 [  51.25  128.  ]
 [  66.76   74.  ]
 [  30.26   14.  ]
 [  61.7   148.  ]
 [  51.14   54.  ]
 [  64.8   137.  ]
 [  52.49  100.  ]
 [  48.25   56.  ]
 [  55.24  108.  ]
 [  38.74  115.  ]
 [  41.48   51.  ]
 [  51.2   104.  ]
 [  51.25  136.  ]
 [  73.73  116.  ]
 [  66.05  147.  ]
 [  40.84   15.  ]
 [  57.85   58.  ]
 [  39.2   110.  ]
 [  67.13   75.  ]
 [  46.98  145.  ]
 [  55.78   77.  ]
 [  62.08   76.  ]
 [  46.28   65.  ]
 [  46.21  140.  ]
 [  48.8    86.  ]
 [  60.84  112.  ]
 [  62.6   144.  ]
 [  76.85  124.  ]
 [  48.8   143.  ]
 [  47.53  139.  ]
 [  43.97  141.  ]
 [  68.29   52.  ]
 [  51.25  120.  ]
 [  50.57   50.  ]
 [  45.    102.  ]
 [  57.22  129.  ]
 [  54.5   107.  ]
 [  57.22  125.  ]
 [  40.93  130.  ]
 [  56.48  109.  ]
 [  55.78  118.  ]
 [  53.89  105.  ]
 [  45.94  122.  ]
 [  51.25  135.  ]
 [  50.    117.  ]
 [  43.81  131.  ]]
```

Comment: This is a very related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901218/numpy-argsort-what-is-it-doing

Answer (score 16):

`distance.argsort()` returns an array of indices. The `ith` index does *not* tell you the rank of the `ith` element in `distance`. Rather, the `ith` index tells you that the `ith` element in the sorted array is `distance[i]`.

In other words,

```
idx = distance.argsort()
assert (distance[idx] == np.sort(distance)).all()
```

Consider this small example [from the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
In [236]: x = np.array([3, 1, 2])

In [237]: np.argsort(x)
Out[237]: array([1, 2, 0])

In [238]: x[np.argsort(x)]
Out[238]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [239]: x[1], x[2], x[0]
Out[239]: (1, 2, 3)
```

---

Calling `argsort` twice does gives you the rank of the `ith` element in `distance`:

```
In [240]: np.argsort(np.argsort(x))
Out[240]: array([2, 0, 1])
```

Understanding how this works is a good test of your understanding of `argsort`. However, calling `argsort` twice to find the rank is inefficient. Especially for larger arrays [there are other, faster, ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284646/190597) to find the rank.

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me:

```
distance.sort()
```

which returns

```
array([ 25.54,  27.49,  27.77,  28.36,  29.  ,  29.6 ,  29.77,  30.26,
        30.29,  30.77,  31.4 ,  32.04,  32.04,  32.26,  32.33,  32.33,
        32.65,  32.72,  33.01,  33.62,  33.62,  34.  ,  34.12,  34.33,
        34.6 ,  34.6 ,  35.24,  35.54,  35.89,  36.01,  36.01,  36.5 ,
        36.56,  36.56,  36.9 ,  36.97,  37.01,  37.25,  37.25,  37.57,
        37.61,  37.96,  38.16,  38.26,  38.26,  38.6 ,  38.65,  38.74,
        39.2 ,  39.25,  39.29,  39.7 ,  39.77,  40.33,  40.33,  40.36,
        40.36,  40.4 ,  40.45,  40.45,  40.45,  40.72,  40.72,  40.84,
        40.84,  40.9 ,  40.93,  40.93,  40.93,  40.93,  41.48,  41.49,
        41.78,  42.5 ,  42.85,  43.28,  43.29,  43.81,  43.81,  43.85,
        43.97,  44.37,  44.37,  44.41,  44.98,  45.  ,  45.05,  45.05,
        45.05,  45.62,  45.94,  45.94,  46.21,  46.21,  46.28,  46.85,
        46.93,  46.98,  47.53,  47.56,  47.89,  48.1 ,  48.25,  48.8 ,
        48.8 ,  49.37,  49.64,  50.  ,  50.09,  50.57,  50.58,  50.58,
        51.14,  51.2 ,  51.2 ,  51.25,  51.25,  51.25,  51.25,  51.85,
        51.97,  52.49,  52.56,  53.89,  53.89,  54.08,  54.5 ,  54.5 ,
        54.5 ,  55.24,  55.78,  55.78,  56.48,  57.22,  57.22,  57.22,
        57.85,  59.24,  59.41,  60.84,  61.7 ,  62.08,  62.6 ,  64.8 ,
        66.05,  66.76,  67.13,  68.29,  73.73,  76.85])
```