# "Rank" DataFrame columns per row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a Time Series `DataFrame` is it possible to create a new `DataFrame` with the same dimensions but the values are the ranking for each row compared to other columns (ordered smallest value first)?

**Example:**

```
                 ABC      DEFG      HIJK       XYZ
date                                              
2018-01-14  0.110541  0.007615  0.063217  0.002543
2018-01-21  0.007012  0.042854  0.061271  0.007988
2018-01-28  0.085946  0.177466  0.046432  0.069297
2018-02-04  0.018278  0.065254  0.038972  0.027278
2018-02-11  0.071785  0.033603  0.075826  0.073270
```

The first row would become:

```
            ABC  DEFG  HIJK  XYZ
date                            
2018-01-14    4     2     3    1
```

as `XYZ` has the smallest value in that row and `ABC` the largest.

[`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) looks like it *might* help however as it outputs the location itself I have not managed to get it to work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double `argsort` for [rank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31910467) per rows and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.argsort().argsort() + 1, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
            ABC  DEFG  HIJK  XYZ
date                            
2018-01-14    4     2     3    1
2018-01-21    1     3     4    2
2018-01-28    3     4     1    2
2018-02-04    1     4     3    2
2018-02-11    2     1     4    3
```

Or use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with method='dense':

```
df1 = df.rank(axis=1, method='dense').astype(int)
print (df1)
            ABC  DEFG  HIJK  XYZ
date                            
2018-01-14    4     2     3    1
2018-01-21    1     3     4    2
2018-01-28    3     4     1    2
2018-02-04    1     4     3    2
2018-02-11    2     1     4    3
```

Comment: `df.rank()` looks like a more natural solution for this requirement. Upvoted +1