# Pandas/numpy help vectorizing sequence of lookup, calculation and reordering across dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to process data from three (csv) files say p, c, f:

- In p, each row has labels
- In c, each row has scores for labels in corresponding row in p (p is matched to c)
- In f, each row is a label and another score

For e.g., loaded into df_p, df_c and df_f respectively:

```
>>> df_p
       p1   p2   p3   p4   p5
2614  104  104  102  102  102
3735  100  103  101  100  104
1450  100  102  100  102  102
>>> df_c
            c1        c2        c3        c4        c5
2614  0.338295  0.190882  0.157231  0.135776  0.177816
3735  0.097800  0.124296  0.268475  0.265111  0.244319
1450  0.160922  0.403703  0.122390  0.130612  0.182373
>>> df_f
            c
100  0.183946
101  0.290311
102  0.192049
103  0.725704
104  0.143359
```

Algo

```
For each row in df_p, df_c: 
  1. update each score in df_c row with df_c * df_f[label] where label is from p
  2. reorder elements of df_c in descending scores
  3. reorder elements in df_p with order from df_c
```

For eg, the first calculated cell in `df_c` will be `0.338295*0.143359`

this is the code I have that's working albeit very very slowly:

```
np_p = []
np_c = []
for i in range(len(df_p)):

    ## determine revised scores
    # Step 1. Revise scores
    r_conf = df_c.iloc[[i]].values[0] # scores for row
    r_place_id = df_p.iloc[[i]].values[0] # labels for row
    p_c = df_f.ix[r_place_id].c.values # class conf for labels
    t_conf = r_conf*p_c # total score

    # Reorder labels
    # Step 2. reorder by revised score
    c = np.sort(t_conf)[::-1]
    c_sort = np.argsort(t_conf)[::-1] 
    # Step 3. reorder labels with revised score order
    p_sort = df_p.iloc[[i]][df_p.columns[c_sort]].values
    np_c.append(c)
    np_p.append(p_sort)
```

Ideally I'd like to create a dataframe like `df_p` and `df_c` but with the reordered and revised values (in `np_p` and `np_c`).

Any ideas on how I can make this go faster.

Thanks!!!

Comment: There are five column to use.   2. reorder elements of df_c in descending scores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`DateFrame.replace` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace the values in `df_p` with values from `df_f`:

```
In [124]: df_pf = df_p.replace(df_f['c']); df_pf
Out[124]: 
            p1        p2        p3        p4        p5
2614  0.143359  0.143359  0.192049  0.192049  0.192049
3735  0.183946  0.725704  0.290311  0.183946  0.143359
1450  0.183946  0.192049  0.183946  0.192049  0.192049
```

Since Pandas aligns indices before multiplying two DataFrames, if we strip the
`p`s and `c`s off the column labels, then we could obtain the desired products
using `df_pf.mul(df_c)`:

```
df_pf.columns = df_pf.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df_c.columns = df_c.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df_c = df_pf.mul(df_c)
```

The correct order for the columns for each row can be obtained using `np.argsort` with `axis=1` specified. The `order` array returned by `np.argsort` can then be used to reorder `df_c` and `df_p`:

```
order = np.argsort(-df_c.values, axis=1)
nrows, ncols = df_c.shape
np_c = df_c.values[np.arange(nrows)[:,None], order]
np_p = df_p.values[np.arange(nrows)[:,None], order]
```

The above uses NumPy's [advanced integer indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to reorder the values in each row separately.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_p = pd.DataFrame({'p1': [104, 100, 100],
 'p2': [104, 103, 102],
 'p3': [102, 101, 100],
 'p4': [102, 100, 102],
 'p5': [102, 104, 102]}, index=[2614,3735,1450])

df_c = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0.33829499999999996, 0.097799999999999998, 0.16092200000000001],
 'c2': [0.190882, 0.124296, 0.40370300000000003],
 'c3': [0.15723099999999998, 0.26847500000000002, 0.12239000000000001],
 'c4': [0.13577600000000001, 0.26511099999999999, 0.13061199999999998],
 'c5': [0.177816, 0.24431900000000001, 0.18237300000000001]}, index=[2614,3735,1450])

df_f = pd.DataFrame({'c': [0.183946,
  0.29031099999999999,
  0.192049,
  0.72570400000000002,
  0.14335899999999999]}, index=list(range(100,105)))

def using_pandas(df_p, df_c, df_f):
    # this works no matter the order of the columns and rows of `df_p` and `df_c`.
    # aligns `df_p` and `df_c` based on the numeric part of their column names
    df_pf = df_p.replace(df_f['c'])
    # change the column names to match since Pandas will align the indices before multiplying
    df_pf.columns = df_pf.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
    df_c.columns = df_c.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
    df_c = df_pf.mul(df_c)
    order = np.argsort(-df_c.values, axis=1)
    nrows, ncols = df_c.shape
    np_c = df_c.values[np.arange(nrows)[:,None], order]
    np_p = df_p.values[np.arange(nrows)[:,None], order]
    return np_c, np_p

np_c, np_p = using_pandas(df_p, df_c, df_f)
print(np_c)
print(np_p)
```

yields

```
[[ 0.04849763  0.03414938  0.03019606  0.02736465  0.02607565]
 [ 0.0902021   0.07794125  0.04876611  0.03502533  0.01798992]
 [ 0.07753076  0.03502455  0.02960096  0.0250839   0.02251315]]
[[104 102 102 104 102]
 [103 101 100 104 100]
 [102 102 100 102 100]]
```

---

Alternatively, if the columns and rows of `df_p` and `df_c` are already aligned, 
then you can gain a bit more speed by doing the multiplication in NumPy instead of Pandas:

```
def using_numpy(df_p, df_c, df_f):
    # faster than using_pandas, but assumes `df_p` and `df_c` are already aligned
    df_pf = df_p.replace(df_f['c'])
    df_pf = df_pf.values
    df_c = df_c.values
    df_p = df_p.values
    df_c = df_pf * df_c
    order = np.argsort(-df_c, axis=1)
    nrows, ncols = df_c.shape
    np_c = df_c[np.arange(nrows)[:,None], order]
    np_p = df_p[np.arange(nrows)[:,None], order]
    return np_c, np_p
```

For these small DataFrames, `using_numpy` is slightly faster than `using_pandas`.
The difference in speed would be more pronounced if the DataFrames were larger.
But again, note that `using_numpy` relies on the indices already being aligned.

```
In [138]: %timeit using_numpy(df_p, df_c, df_f)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop

In [139]: %timeit using_pandas(df_p, df_c, df_f)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
```

Comment: .@unutbu. can you explain np.argsort(-df_c, axis=1)?

Comment: @Merlin: [`np.argsort`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17901218/190597) returns the indices that would sort an array. For example, `np.argsort([1,3,2])` returns `array([0, 2, 1])` since to sort `[1,3,2]` in ascending order the 0th item comes first, then the 2nd, then the 1st. `np.argsort([[1,3,2],[20,30,10]], axis=1)` is similar to row_stacking `np.argsort([1,3,2])` and `np.argsort([20,30,10])`. A minus sign is used in `np.argsort(-df_c, axis=1)` to argsort each row of `df_c` in *descending order*.

Comment: @unutbu - works great, complete and good intuition! I had to break the dataframe into chunks to fit into memory since my data is much larger than the sample above but otherwise very succinct and elegant and I learnt a few tricks. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: First create a dict of `df_f`

```
di = df_f['c'].to_dict()

   {100: 0.183946,
 101: 0.29031099999999999,
 102: 0.192049,
 103: 0.72570400000000002,
 104: 0.14335899999999999}
```

Then map it to df_p:

```
df_p.replace(di)

#            p1        p2        p3        p4        p5
# 2614  0.143359  0.143359  0.192049  0.192049  0.192049
# 3735  0.183946  0.725704  0.290311  0.183946  0.143359
# 1450  0.183946  0.192049  0.183946  0.192049  0.192049
```

Then do your multiplication:

```
df_c2 =df_c.copy() 
df_c2['c1'] = df_c['c1']* df_p['p1'] 
df_c2['c2'] = df_c['c2']* df_p['p2'] 
df_c2['c3'] = df_c['c3']* df_p['p3'] 
df_c2['c4'] = df_c['c4']* df_p['p4'] 
df_c2['c5'] = df_c['c5']* df_p['p5'] 

 #              c1        c2        c3        c4        c5
 #   2614  0.048498  0.027365  0.030196  0.026076  0.034149
 #   3735  0.017990  0.090202  0.077941  0.048766  0.035025
 #   1450  0.029601  0.077531  0.022513  0.025084  0.035025
```