# pandas sort rows by index using a custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I often need to work with dataframes where the rownames (index in pandas) are like of the type `[a-z][0-9]+` (e.g. 'a20','a21',... or 'b1','b11','b2',...)

I would like to be able to sort the rows based on the number alone. From what I can gather of the API, `df.sort_index()` does not take a function argument where I can define the sorting function.

Is there a neat way of achieving this without resorting to removing the initial characters when creating the dataframe?

Comment: Perhaps you can use reindex.

Comment: i think the current best approach is to construct a column from the index with the letter prefixes removed, and sort by that.

Comment: I feel like the best theoretical way to do this is to have a multi-index of one string column and one integer column, then you can use standard pandas sorting and features.  However, one of the current answers might very well be a better practical answer since multi-indexes introduce more complexity.

Comment: I agree with @HaleemurAli, but only if the numeric part of the index is a unique identifier.  I.e. how do you want to deal with A25 & B25 (if that is possible).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), convert to `int` and get position of sorted values by `argsort`, last use `iloc`:

(borrowing data from @Dark):

```
df = df.iloc[df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort()]
print (df)
     0
a5   5
a6   6
a10  2
a11  3
b11  7
a12  1
b12  8
a15  4
```

**Explanation**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],index=['a12','a10','a11','a15','a5','a6','b11','b12'])
print (df)
     0
a12  1
a10  2
a11  3
a15  4
a5   5
a6   6
b11  7
b12  8
```

First [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) all integers:

```
print (df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False))
Index(['12', '10', '11', '15', '5', '6', '11', '12'], dtype='object')
```

Cast to `integer`s:

```
print (df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int))
Int64Index([12, 10, 11, 15, 5, 6, 11, 12], dtype='int64')
```

Get positions of sorted values by [argsort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17901218/2901002):

```
print (df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort())
[4 5 1 2 6 0 7 3]
```

Last select values by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort()])
     0
a5   5
a6   6
a10  2
a11  3
b11  7
a12  1
b12  8
a15  4
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what this does? It's cool that it seems to work but I'd like to be able to understand what it does :)

Answer (score 2):

By using `natsort`  sort by index list then `reindex`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'v':[1,2,3]},index=['b1','b11','b2'])

from natsort import natsorted, ns


df.reindex(natsorted(df.index.tolist(), alg=ns.IGNORECASE))

Out[795]: 
     v
b1   1
b2   3
b11  2
```

Comment: You were a bit quicker

Comment: @Dark yep , just a little bit :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sorted and reindex i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],index=['a12','a10','a11','a15','a5','a6','b11','b12'])

import re
df.reindex(sorted(df.index,key=lambda x: re.sub('[A-z]','',x)))


    0
a10  2
a11  3
b11  7
a12  1
b12  8
a15  4
a5   5
a6   6
```

Comment: I think need convert to `int` :)