# Sort pandas dataframe based on two columns that are similar but one will be NaN if the other has a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a merged df which has 2 experiment IDs - experiment_a and experiment_b

They are in the general nomenclature EXPT_YEAR_NUM but some have add ons, of do not have a year instead of some other value. In this df where there is a value in experiment_a, experiment_b = NaN, and vice versa.

ie:

```
experiment_a    experiment_b
EXPT_2011_06     NaN
NaN              EXPT_2011_07
```

How do I sort so that the ascending values of experiment_a and _b are together, instead of it ascending on experiment_a with _b having all NaN values, then ascending with experiment_b when experiment_a have NaN values?

This is what happens when i use sort_values:

```
df = df.sort_values(['experiment_a', 'experiment_b'])
```

It clearly just sorts _a first, then _b.

Comment: Use `where` to construct a single column?

Comment: Can you add more values to sample with expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for `Series`, then get indices of sorted values by [`argsort`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17901218/2901002) and last select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - output is sorted columns:

```
print (df)
   experiment_a  experiment_b
0  EXPT_2011_06           NaN
1  EXPT_2010_06           NaN
2           NaN  EXPT_2011_07

df = df.iloc[df['experiment_a'].fillna(df['experiment_b']).argsort()]
print (df)
   experiment_a  experiment_b
1  EXPT_2010_06           NaN
0  EXPT_2011_06           NaN
2           NaN  EXPT_2011_07
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['experiment_a'].fillna(df['experiment_b']))
0    EXPT_2011_06
1    EXPT_2010_06
2    EXPT_2011_07
Name: experiment_a, dtype: object

print (df['experiment_a'].fillna(df['experiment_b']).argsort())
0    1
1    0
2    2
Name: experiment_a, dtype: int64
```

I test more solutions, with `np.where` is a bit better performace, but mainly it depends of data:

```
print (df)
   experiment_a  experiment_b
0  EXPT_2011_03           NaN
1           NaN  EXPT_2009_08
2           NaN  EXPT_2010_06
3  EXPT_2010_07           NaN
4           NaN  EXPT_2011_07

#[500000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [41]: %timeit (df.iloc[(np.where(df['experiment_a'].isnull(), df['experiment_b'], df['experiment_a'])).argsort()])
1 loop, best of 3: 318 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit (df.iloc[df['experiment_a'].fillna(df['experiment_b']).argsort()])
1 loop, best of 3: 335 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit (df.iloc[df['experiment_a'].combine_first(df['experiment_b']).argsort()])
1 loop, best of 3: 333 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit (df.iloc[df.experiment_a.where(df.experiment_a.notnull(), df.experiment_b).argsort()])
1 loop, best of 3: 342 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

First construct a single column:

```
key = df.experiment_a.where(df.experiment_a.notnull(), df.experiment_b)
```

Then indices:

```
idx = key.argsort()
```

Finally:

```
df.iloc[idx]
```