# How to sort dataframe with ignoring prefixes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I can sort dataframe by column like this:

```
df.sort(columns='sort_index', inplace=True)
```

And I can sort array with ignoring prefixes like this:

```
array.sort(key=lambda element: re.sub(re, "", element))
```

But how to sort dataframe with ignoring prefixes?

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: Add a "key" column to your dataframe with the re.sub logic then sort on that "key".  After sort, `drop('key', axis=1)`.  Plus you'll need to use `sort_values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`argsort`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17901218/2901002) for indices and then select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) what reorder rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': list(range(9)), 
}, index=['1s','2d','2a','1c','22d','1b','2b','1c','4d'])
print (df)
     B
1s   0
2d   1
2a   2
1c   3
22d  4
1b   5
2b   6
1c   7
4d   8

idx = df.index.str.replace('\D+', '').astype(int).argsort()
df = df.iloc[idx]
print (df)
     B
1s   0
1c   3
1b   5
1c   7
2d   1
2a   2
2b   6
4d   8
22d  4
```