# Sorting pandas.DataFrame in python sorted() function manner

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

### Description

Long story short, I need a way to sort a DataFrame by a specific column, given a specific function which is analagous to usage of "key" parameter in python built-in sorted() function. Yet there's no such "key" parameter in `pd.DataFrame.sort_value()` function.

### The approach used for now

I have to create a new column to store the "scores" of a specific row, and delete it in the end. The problem of this approach is that the necessity to generate a column name which does not exists in the DataFrame, and it could be more troublesome when it comes to sorting by multiple columns.

I wonder if there's a more suitable way for such purpose, in which there's no need to come up with a new column name, just like using a sorted() function and specifying parameter "key" in it.

**Update**: I changed my implementation by using a new object instead of generating a new string beyond those in the columns to avoid collision, as shown in the code below.

### Code

Here goes the example code. In this sample the DataFrame is needed to be sort according to the length of the data in row "snippet". **Please don't make additional assumptions on the type of the objects** in each rows of the specific column. The only thing given is the column itself and a function object/lambda expression (in this example: len) that takes each object in the column as input and produce a value, which is used for comparison.

```
def sort_table_by_key(self, ascending=True, key=len):
    """
    Sort the table inplace.
    """
    # column_tmp = "".join(self._table.columns)
    column_tmp = object() # Create a new object to avoid column name collision.
    # Calculate the scores of the objects. 
    self._table[column_tmp] = self._table["snippet"].apply(key)
    self._table.sort_values(by=column_tmp, ascending=ascending, inplace=True)
    del self._table[column_tmp]
```

Comment: Note that this is now supported with the `key` argument to sort_values and sort_index`.

Answer (score 1):

Now this is not implemented, check [github issue 3942](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3942).

I think you need [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and then select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['assdsd','sda','affd','asddsd','ffb','sdb','db','cf','d'],
    'B': list(range(9))
})
print (df)
        A  B
0  assdsd  0
1     sda  1
2    affd  2
3  asddsd  3
4     ffb  4
5     sdb  5
6      db  6
7      cf  7
8       d  8
```

---

```
def sort_table_by_length(column, ascending=True):
    if ascending:
        return df.iloc[df[column].str.len().argsort()]
    else:
        return df.iloc[df[column].str.len().argsort()[::-1]]

print (sort_table_by_length('A'))
        A  B
8       d  8
6      db  6
7      cf  7
1     sda  1
4     ffb  4
5     sdb  5
2    affd  2
0  assdsd  0
3  asddsd  3

print (sort_table_by_length('A', False))
        A  B
3  asddsd  3
0  assdsd  0
2    affd  2
5     sdb  5
4     ffb  4
1     sda  1
7      cf  7
6      db  6
8       d  8
```

**How it working**:

First get lengths to new `Series`:

```
print (df['A'].str.len())
0    6
1    3
2    4
3    6
4    3
5    3
6    2
7    2
8    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Then get indices by sorted values by [argmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901218/numpy-argsort-what-is-it-doing), for descending ordering is used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486305):

```
print (df['A'].str.len().argsort())
0    8
1    6
2    7
3    1
4    4
5    5
6    2
7    0
8    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Last change ordering by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[df['A'].str.len().argsort()])
        A  B
8       d  8
6      db  6
7      cf  7
1     sda  1
4     ffb  4
5     sdb  5
2    affd  2
0  assdsd  0
3  asddsd  3
```

Comment: I apologize for not stating my problems clearly. The problem is that I need a general way (instead of those suits only strings or 1d np.ndarray(which is my case)) to a sort DataFrame by a specific column, given a pre-defined function that takes each objects (they are not necessarily strings) in that column as input and produce a "score", according to which the DataFrame would be sorted (just like the "key" parameter in built-in sorted() function. I don't wan't to create a new column for the DataFrame to store those "scores" in case the names of columns collides.

Comment: @BorisPolonsky - Unfortunately this is not implemented [yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3942) in pandas. So now does not exist some general solution. Need create sorting numeric Series like `df[column].str.len()` and then use `argsort`. No new column is added.

Comment: How about I create a Series that stores the scores outside the data, sort the series itself, and use it for .iloc to avoid column name collision.

Comment: @BorisPolonsky - this do exacly my solution.