# Rank elements of numpy list in descending order

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I need to return the indexes that the elements of a list would have if the list was sorted in descending order.

For example given `np.array([2,3,1,4,5])` I would like to receive `array([3,2,4,1,0])`.

Is there an easy way to obtain such an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy argsort - what is it doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901218/numpy-argsort-what-is-it-doing)

Comment: No, but I found way to better describe what I want. I'd like to rank the elements of the array in descending order, such as what is done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice?noredirect=1&lq=1
but in descending rather than ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the *ranks* your elements would have in descending order.

```
a = np.array([2,3,1,4,5])
sorted_indices = np.argsort(-a)
ranks = np.empty_like(sorted_indices)
ranks[sorted_indices] = np.arange(len(a))
```

And result:

```
>>> ranks
array([3, 2, 4, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use numpy's argsort (and it looks like you want the reverse order?)

```
a = np.array([2,3,1,4,5])
np.argsort(-a)
```